# Laravel echo sessions with subdomains

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-echo

I've currently run into an issue using Laravel Echo Server on our staging/production servers. Locally, everything works as intended, but deploying to our staging servers has been a bit of a nightmare. As it stands right now, public channels work properly, but we get an authentication error when trying to join a private channel.

I've narrowed this down to being a session issue, where the session isn't being sent along with the socket requests. This seems to be because the staging servers are routed to person.staging.website.com, but the socket server had to be setup at ws.website.com because of some complications with AWS not allowing us access to the SSL certificate to configure the echo server. So we setup a subdomain with a Lets Encrypt to get it up and running.

Now, I realize that I can just change the SESSION_DOMAIN in our .env's to be .website.com, but I'm getting some pushback since people won't be able to be logged into different subdomains at the same time. Is there any way I can set up Laravel's sessions to work with two different, specific subdomains instead of wildcarding every subdomain? For testing, I'd need to set it up at person.staging.website and ws.website.com, but production would need different values.

Any suggestions or clever work-arounds for this?

Comment: Give a try to set .env value for SESSION_DOMAIN dynamically from url and verify each url from database.